# Task Manager: Make GPU Utilization Percentage Reflect CUDA

Tags: windows-10, gpu, task-manager

**I am specifically asking about the utilization as shown in the left-hand (overview) panel, not about the utilization as shown in the right hand (main / detailed view) panel.**

I do a lot of computational work on a shared workstation, and that work ends up being reflected in CUDA utilization for the workstation's GPUs.  This can be displayed in the Windows 10 task manager by going to a particular GPU under the Performance tab, and then changing the graph to display CUDA:

[image: Task Manager window showing GPU 0 CUDA maxed out, but utilization of only 4%]

However, you'll notice from the screenshot that the GPU utilization remains at 4% (based on the current 3D utilization, which is the default graph and first option in the list) regardless of what is selected for the graph.  The mini-graph in the left panel also only displays the 3D utilization.  This means that checking whether a particular GPU is being used for a compute task by another user on the shared workstation requires opening each GPU and observing the graph (or, more realistically, looking at the GPU temperatures to see if they're doing any kind of work).

It's not a huge problem or anything, but I'm wondering if the percentage in the left panel could be made to reflect the current CUDA utilization rather than the default of reflecting the 3D utilization (which is always low or zero and thus not very useful).  Likewise for the mini graph in the left panel.  More generally, can the percentage / mini graph be made to reflect any arbitrary aspect of GPU utilization (e.g. video encode/decode, copy, CUDA, VR, etc...) which is available to view in the main graph in the task manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the CUDA usage graph in the Task Manager :

- Start the Task Manager
- Switch to the Performance tab
- Click on the GPU on the left
- Click the "Copy" drop-down list in the upper part
- Select "Cuda" from the list.

For more information with screenshots, see the article
[GPU Monitoring on Windows 10 for Machine Learning & CUDA](https://michaelceber.medium.com/gpu-monitoring-on-windows-10-for-machine-learning-cuda-41088de86d65).

This is about everything that's possible with the Task Manager.
The Task Manager isn't programmable and doesn't have add-ons.

You may need third party software for that, but I don't know of one.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to write an answer to this question, but if you read a bit more closely you'll see that I already know how to display the CUDA utilization in the main graph.  I am asking specifically about whether it is possible to get the CUDA utilization to appear in the left-hand panel, either in the mini graph or in the percentage display (or both).

Comment: You can't make Windows do anything that it's not already programmed to do. The Task Manager isn't programmable and doesn't have add-ons. You may need third party software for that, if it exists.

Comment: In that case, if you write that into an answer I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I improved my answer with more information.